# Error 3010008: No ABI found

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, abi

I was able to push the contract to the jungle test net but i am unable to run the contract.

i get this error:

Error 3010008: No ABI found

[image]

what am i doing wrong?

thanks.

Comment: Please post the command used to set the contract.  Did you set it to account hello or hello.code?

Comment: this is the command i ran: cleos -u http://jungle.cryptolions.io:18888 set contract manantest hello -p manantest

Comment: Please post the contract's code.  I'm assuming that you compiled the wast/abi before pushing.  I'm specifically interested in how your macro is configured.  Also, you can nano your abi to see if the actions are there.  If they are not, eosiocpp is not seeing/interpreting your macro appropriately

Comment: If I'm setting a contract from the current directory, I would go cleos set contract eoiso ../eosio.token which picks up the web assembly and abi

Answer (score 1):

check your ABI using:

```
cleos get abi YOUR_CONTRACT
```

If returned ABI is null update your contract:

```
cd YOUR_CONTRACT_DIR
cleos set contract YOUR_CONTRACT_ACC . YOUR_CONTRACT.wast YOUR_CONTRACT.abi -p manantest
```

I hope it will help you